# C# How to loop through a list, update the same list, and continue looping?

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I am writing a webscraper that grabs specific urls and adds them to a list.

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;

List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
var firstUrl = "http://example.com";
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument document = web.Load(firstUrl);

HtmlNodeCollection nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'Name')]/a");
            foreach (HtmlNode htmlNode in (IEnumerable<HtmlNode>)nodes)
            {
                if (!mylist.Contains(htmlNode.InnerText))
                {
                    mylist.Add(htmlNode.InnerText);

                }

            }
```

What I want to do at this point is to loop through 'mylist' and do the exact same thing and basically continue forever. The code should be taking newly parsed URLs and adding them to the list. What would be the easiest way to do this?

I tried creating a for loop right after the one above. But it does not seem to be updating the list. It will only continue to loop over the same items already in the list forever (since i will always be less than mylist.Count)

```
for (int i = 0; i < mylist.Count; i++)
            {
                //the items in mylist are added to the url
                var urls = "http://example.com" + mylist[i];

                HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
                HtmlDocument document = web.Load(urls);

                HtmlNodeCollection nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'Name')]/a");
                foreach (HtmlNode htmlNode in (IEnumerable<HtmlNode>)nodes)
                {
                    if (!mylist.Contains(htmlNode.InnerText))
                    { 
                        mylist.Add(htmlNode.InnerText);
                    }

                }


            }
```

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like a good use case for implementing recursion, I'd start by reading up on that.

Comment: Recursion will stackoverflow before long, so it definitely does not sound like a case for recursion ;)

Comment: He wants a Queue

Comment: or build this right with, `TPDataflow`, and a transform block that feeds into itself, with a `CancelationToken`,  something better than htmlweb that uses `async` and `await` to be nice to your resources, and a big nasty dictionary so you are not scraping in circles! and all thats left to do is.... everything

Comment: @TheGeneral Oh yeah, fair call!

Comment: Why not store the URLs that are found in a database table?   This allows will gain you the advantage of having and indexes, making checking that if you already have that URL faster as your list grows.  It also allows you to store the date time a URL was last visited, and if you do it right, even allow you to run multiple scrapers using the same list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Queue`  fit for your requirement.

```
Queue<string> mylist = new Queue<string>();
```

First pass :

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;

Queue<string> mylist = new Queue<string>();
var firstUrl = "http://example.com";
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument document = web.Load(firstUrl);

HtmlNodeCollection nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'Name')]/a");
            foreach (HtmlNode htmlNode in (IEnumerable<HtmlNode>)nodes)
            {
                if (!mylist.Contains(htmlNode.InnerText))
                {
                    mylist.Enqueue(htmlNode.InnerText);

                }
            }
```

Now the second pass

```
while (mylist.Count > 0)
            {
                var url = mylist..Dequeue();
                //the items in mylist are added to the url
                var urls = "http://example.com" + url;

                HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
                HtmlDocument document = web.Load(urls);

                HtmlNodeCollection nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'Name')]/a");
                foreach (HtmlNode htmlNode in (IEnumerable<HtmlNode>)nodes)
                {
                    if (!mylist.Contains(htmlNode.InnerText))
                    { 
                        mylist.Enqueue(htmlNode.InnerText);
                    }

                }


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible (dangerous ?) implementation using recursion that will produces urls as they are consumed:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Scrap(string url)
{
    var web = new HtmlWeb();
    var seenUrls = new HashSet<string>();
    return ScrapImpl(web, seenUrls, url);
}

private IEnumerable<string> ScrapImpl(HtmlWeb web, HashSet<string> seenUrls, string baseUrl)
{
    var document = web.Load(baseUrl);
    foreach (var node in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'Name')]/a"))
    {
        yield return node.InnerText;
        if (seenUrls.Add(node.InnerText))
        {
            foreach (var childUrl in ScrapImpl(web, seenUrls, baseUrl + node.InnerText))
            {
                yield return childUrl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var urls = Scrap("http://example.com"); //nothing is done yet
foreach(var url in urls) //http://example.com starts beeing scraped at this point
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go NuGet "System.Interactive" and then do this:

```
var found = new HashSet<string>();

var urls =
    EnumerableEx
        .Expand(
            new[] { "http://example.com" },
            url =>
            {
                var web = new HtmlWeb();
                var document = web.Load(url);
                var nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'Name')]/a");
                return
                    nodes
                        .Cast<HtmlNode>()
                        .Select(x => x.InnerText)
                        .Where(x => !found.Contains(x))
                        .Do(x => found.Add(x))
                        .Select(x => "http://example.com" + x);
            });
```